# Text of xp cmdshell not allowed

Tags: support

I was over on dba.stackexchange and I noticed every time I went to edit my question to add more detail, my save would never return. Long story short, it seems that [xp_ cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) (no space) pooches whatever you're doing on a stackexchange site. Searching on that term times out, having it in the body of a question never saves.  Tested with Opera 11.x on Mac OSX and Camino 2.0.7

Am I insane or is this a bug? I couldn't search for the this to see if it's an open issue so sorry if it's common knowledge

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xp_cmdshell loads fine for me

Comment: @balpha woks fine for me as well, and returns [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016669/getting-execute-permission-to-xp-cmdshell) which is on xp_cmdshell, but perhaps it because I'm using Android?

Comment: Weird, I get "408 Request Time-out Your browser didn't send a complete request in time" hitting the above link. I'll reboot everything later on, must be something strange with my environment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is some form of antivirus, proxy, or firewall between you and us trying to "protect" you by preventing "dangerous" text from appearing in your browser.

Every time this has come up, that has been the answer. Trust me -- it ain't us.

Answer (score 0):

There are firewalls that are able to filter the network traffic for SQL keywords and statements (at least Cisco has such features), and for other things too.

A work-around would be to connect to StackOverflow / StackExchange sites using `HTTPS`. Then you should be able to post. This is due to `HTTPS` traffic being encrypted so your posting won't be in human (in this case computer) readable format. The firewall cannot sniff your posts any longer.

For example just call https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of https://stackoverflow.com/.